# Djikstra's algorithm not working with heaps in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, heap, greedy

I want to implement Djikstra Algorithm using heaps for the challenge problem [in this file](http://www.algorithmsilluminated.org/datasets/problem9.8.txt)  [at this page's module](http://www.algorithmsilluminated.org/) -> Test Cases and Data Sets for Programming Projects -> Programming Problems 9.8 and 10.8: Implementing Dijkstra's Algorithm

I have implemented Djikstra Algorithm using heaps and naive method. The naive method works for the challenge problem but the one using heaps have dissimilar and incorrect results.

I've created a function testcase() that returns the networkx graph having the nodes, vertices and weights of the challenge problem.
I pass this graph returned by testcase() to the below Djikstra Algorithm implementations.

Djikstra Algorithm using naive implementation:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import networkx as nx
import heapq
import numpy as np

def undirected_djikstra_naive(DG, source, destination):
    X = [source]
    A = {}
    A[source] = 0
    all_nodes = list(DG.nodes)
    minimum_2nd_overall = float('inf')
    w_overall = float('inf')
    print("Naive:")
    while len(X) != len(all_nodes):
        for edge in list(DG.edges):
            if (edge[0] in X) and (edge[1] not in X):
                edge_tail = edge[0]
                edge_head = edge[1]
            elif (edge[1] in X) and (edge[0] not in X):
                edge_tail = edge[1]
                edge_head = edge[0]
            if ((edge_tail in X) and (edge_head not in X)) :
                dji_greedy = A[edge_tail] + DG.edges[edge_tail, edge_head]['weight'] #djikstra's greedy criterion
                if edge_head not in A:
                    A[edge_head] = dji_greedy
                elif dji_greedy < A[edge_head]:
                    A[edge_head] = dji_greedy
                if dji_greedy < minimum_2nd_overall:
                    minimum_2nd_overall = dji_greedy
                    w_overall = edge_head  
        minimum_2nd_overall = float('inf')
        X.append(w_overall)
    #print("Printing minimum distances from starting vertex {}".format(source))
    B = []
    for node in A:
        if node in destination:
            #print("Vertex {} is at distance {}".format(node, A[node]))
            B.append([node, A[node]])
    B = sorted(B)
    return B
```

Djikstra Algorithm using heap implementation:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import networkx as nx
import heapq
import numpy as np

def undirected_djikstra_heap(DG, source, destination):
    #Heap implementation which does the following
    #
    # 1. For vertices in X, find all edges originating from them to all vertices not in X
    # 2. Keep track of minimum value of len(w) + lwv
    # 3. Return w, v and lwv
    X = [source]
    minHeap = []
    heapq.heappush(minHeap, [0, source])
    all_nodes = list(DG.nodes)
    for node in all_nodes:
        DG.nodes[node]['shortest_dist'] = float('inf') 
    print("Heap:")
    while len(minHeap) != 0:
        w = heapq.heappop(minHeap)
        #print(minHeap)
        X.append(w[1])
        DG.nodes[w[1]]['shortest_dist'] = w[0]
        for edge in list(DG.edges):
            if (edge[0] == w[1]) and (edge[1] not in X):
                edge_tail = edge[0]
                edge_head = edge[1]
            elif (edge[1] == w[1]) and (edge[0] not in X):
                edge_tail = edge[1]
                edge_head = edge[0]
            else:
                continue
            if ((edge_tail == w[1]) and (edge_head not in X)) : # node that has just been popped should be the tail
                dji_greedy = w[0] + DG.edges[edge_tail, edge_head]['weight'] #djikstra's greedy criterion
                if len(minHeap) == 0:
                    heapq.heappush(minHeap, [dji_greedy, edge_head])
                    continue
                singlenp = [i[1] for i in minHeap]
                if edge_head not in singlenp:
                    heapq.heappush(minHeap, [dji_greedy, edge_head])
                else:
                    dest_idx = singlenp.index(edge_head)
                    if dji_greedy < minHeap[dest_idx][0]:
                        minHeap[dest_idx] = minHeap[0]
                        heapq.heappop(minHeap)
                        heapq.heappush(minHeap, [dji_greedy, edge_head])
    #print("Printing minimum distances from starting vertex \'{}\'".format(source))
    B = []
    for node in all_nodes:
        if node in destination:
            #print("Vertex {} is at distance {}".format(node, DG.nodes[node]['shortest_dist']))
            B.append([node, DG.nodes[node]['shortest_dist']])
    B = sorted(B)
    return B
```

Calling and asserting the algorithm:

```py
challenge_graph_g = testcase()
start_vert = 1
dest_verts = challenge_graph_g.nodes
heap_dji = undirected_djikstra_heap(challenge_graph_g, start_vert, dest_verts)
naive_dji = undirected_djikstra_naive(challenge_graph_g, start_vert , dest_verts)

for a in range(len(dest_verts)):
    assert heap_dji[a][1] == naive_dji[a][1], "Dist Mismatch at Vertex {} dist heap {}, Vertex {} dist naive {}".format(heap_dji[a][0], heap_dji[a][1], naive_dji[a][0], naive_dji[a][1])
```

I'm getting an Assertion error for the vertex 2's output as follows:

AssertionError: Dist Mismatch at Vertex 2 dist heap 3428, Vertex 2 dist naive 2971

I'm not understanding where and for which cases is my heap implementation failing. Please help.

---

### Solution:

Heapify the iterable after manual insert/delete operation on heapq. Performed heapq.heapify(minHeap) after  minHeap[dest_idx] = minHeap[0] manual update on the heap.

Modified Code:

Djikstra Algorithm using heap implementation:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import networkx as nx
import heapq
import numpy as np

def undirected_djikstra_heap(DG, source, destination):
    #Heap implementation which does the following
    #
    # 1. For vertices in X, find all edges originating from them to all vertices not in X
    # 2. Keep track of minimum value of len(w) + lwv
    # 3. Return w, v and lwv
    X = [source]
    minHeap = []
    heapq.heappush(minHeap, [0, source])
    all_nodes = list(DG.nodes)
    for node in all_nodes:
        DG.nodes[node]['shortest_dist'] = float('inf') 
    print("Heap:")
    while len(minHeap) != 0:
        w = heapq.heappop(minHeap)
        #print(minHeap)
        X.append(w[1])
        DG.nodes[w[1]]['shortest_dist'] = w[0]
        for edge in list(DG.edges):
            if (edge[0] == w[1]) and (edge[1] not in X):
                edge_tail = edge[0]
                edge_head = edge[1]
            elif (edge[1] == w[1]) and (edge[0] not in X):
                edge_tail = edge[1]
                edge_head = edge[0]
            else:
                continue
            if ((edge_tail == w[1]) and (edge_head not in X)) : # node that has just been popped should be the tail
                dji_greedy = w[0] + DG.edges[edge_tail, edge_head]['weight'] #djikstra's greedy criterion
                if len(minHeap) == 0:
                    heapq.heappush(minHeap, [dji_greedy, edge_head])
                    continue
                singlenp = [i[1] for i in minHeap]
                if edge_head not in singlenp:
                    heapq.heappush(minHeap, [dji_greedy, edge_head])
                else:
                    dest_idx = singlenp.index(edge_head)
                    if dji_greedy < minHeap[dest_idx][0]:
                        minHeap[dest_idx] = minHeap[0]
                        heapq.heapify(minHeap)    # Added this single line
                        heapq.heappop(minHeap)
                        heapq.heappush(minHeap, [dji_greedy, edge_head])
    #print("Printing minimum distances from starting vertex \'{}\'".format(source))
    B = []
    for node in all_nodes:
        if node in destination:
            #print("Vertex {} is at distance {}".format(node, DG.nodes[node]['shortest_dist']))
            B.append([node, DG.nodes[node]['shortest_dist']])
    B = sorted(B)
    return B
```

With this modified code, naive implementation and heap implementation of Djikstra Algorithm gives same result on challenge dataset.

Comment: What does this row do `minHeap[dest_idx] = minHeap[0]`? Are you sure that it will still be a correct heap when not using the heapq interface?

Comment: singlenp = [i[1] for i in minHeap]    took the 2nd column of list in list having value of nodes unvisited in graph into singlenp . And I havnt modified it further, so if I take   singlenp.index(edge_head)   then it will give me the exact index where the integer edge_head lies in the minHeap. Hence, I know the index at which to delete from the heap.

Comment: To continue on @O.O. 's comment, beneath the line `minHeap[dest_idx] = minHeap[0]`,  we can see that you do a `heapq.heappop(minHeap)`, meaning that you pop an element from your heap, without treating it correctly (unlike the element that you pop at the top of the while loop). This part of the code looks very suspicious (not using the heapq API interface, and popping and forgetting an element from the queue).

Comment: I have done index based deletion on the heap datastructure. So i should try to heapify the heap after manual update so that it bubbles up the minimum element. Let me try this. Thanks.

Comment: Heap implementation working using heapq.heapify(minHeap) after minHeap[dest_idx] = minHeap[0]. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the heapify call will be linear time; compared to logarithmic for the push/pop calls. It should be possible to not have to delete/change elements from the middle of the heap here so that the complexity is not affected like so. (eg by storing duplicates in heap and checking somewhere else if you already have handled a node). - Might be something to check if the solution seems slow.

Comment: Good ideas. and we can also try to use self implemented heap data structure, because node deletion based on index is just not provided in heapq. or we can override heapq to support deletion.